# Not able to change the Row cell color based on cell name in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Can someone help me how to change the color for row cell color for values in that .I tried do some color change as far as i know but it did not work. Attached the image as i need in the same color . If Call status is sccuess then it should green and fail means red color and so on.Not able to change the Row cell color based on cell name in Tableau[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMWrv.jpg)

Thanks
Adhi

Comment: Please post what you have tried in Tableau so far, as well has the format of your data, and fields you are using

Comment: That's not how Tableau works. You color measure values based on criteria but you can't change a dimension's background color based on a dimension value.

Answer (score 0):

here is a video showing how this is done. a trick using bar chart in the background. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBt37jvOQ7g

Comment: Thanks for the youtube video . But Our project requirement is to keep the report in Tabular format and not in bar charts or graphs.We will create static text in dashboard and will add colors for each text based on requirement.

Comment: The video shows data in tabular format with conditional background color. How would your needs be different from the video?